# Adding Button right of the UiSearchController swift, UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to add an button right to the search controller in the navigation, but am not sure how can I implement that... any Ideas?
Am doing it programmatically

[I want to replicate this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOpsy.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Horizontal StackView and embed a search bar on the left, and a button on the right. Set the button's imageView to the "gear" image or whatever image you'd like.